# Oracle Executemany typerror when having strings and integers

Tags: python, oracle

Been trying to get this working for a while now, any help would be appreciated.
I got this working just using **execute** after each new dict, but it takes about 40 minutes to complete. Trying to get **executemany** to work in hopes of lowering the time it takes.
I have also tried doing *values(:1, :2, ...)*
Any help would be appreciated. 
***TypeError:** Expecting string or bytes object* (At executemany statement)

```
#Connection established with variable name oraCurs...

def returnaDict():
    return {
    #46 fields
    'ID': '', # int
    'STATUS': '', # String
    #...
    #...
    }

#Query ran here

data = list()
for aFeature in query.features:
    newDict = returnaDict()
    newDict['ID'] = aFeature.attributes["ObjectID"]
    newDict['STATUS'] = aFeature.attributes["Status"]
    #...
    data.append(newDict)

oraCurs.executemany("""Insert into table (ID, STATUS, ...) Values (%s, %s,...)""", data)
oraCurs.execute('COMMIT')
```

Comment: what's the source for those values? a file, a list, another table..?

Comment: Read the cx_Oracle documentation [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html) and try the examples like https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BindInsert.py  Then gradually change them to suit your data.

Comment: Another table is the source